# Graphite, how to change request rate to 1 min

Tags: graphite, logstash, statsd

I have recently installed statsd with Graphite.
Statsd is working in logstash:

```
statsd {
 host => "localhost"
 port => 8125
 debug => false
 increment => "%{dhcp}"
```

}

Graphite storage-schemas.conf:

```
[stats]
pattern = ^stats.*
retentions = 5m:500m,600:10080,1800:262974
```

The problem is that all Graphs are per second or 10 seconds, but I need per minute.
How I can change the Graph rate to one minute?

Thank you in advance.
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In statsd's config, add the following to ensure that statsd and graphite are in sync-

> flushInterval: 60000,

Here the count is in milliseconds. This will make statsd send metrics to graphite every minute.

`pattern = ^stats\.`

`retentions = 60s:90d`

Your storage schema isn't falling into the regex because you haven't escaped the period.

A good idea would be to verify the schema that is 'finally applicable' on the metric. A neat way would be to `tailf /opt/graphite/storage/log/carbon-cache/carbon-cache-a/creates.log` Then send a test metric to verify to ascertain what graphite thinks you wants out of it. The output will be something like-

> 24/10/2013 15:05:08 :: new metric
>   METRIC_NAME matched aggregation schema counters_fall_here
>
> 24/10/2013 15:05:08 :: creating database file
>   /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/METRIC_NAME.wsp (archive=[(60, 43200), (600, 52560)] xff=0.0 agg=sum)